# What are raw attribute objects in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, attributes

I'm learning Backbone.js and reading through the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) I have a hard time understanding the below:

```
"If a model property is defined, you may also pass raw attributes objects, and have them be vivified as instances of the model."
```

Looking at [Collection#model](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model), they provided the example:

```
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Book
});
```

But how do I go on from there and "pass raw attributes objects"?

********Edit***********

Ok looking back now I think what this means is that if I have added the model "Book" to the Library collection, now I can do -

```
var lib = new Library;

lib.add([
  {name: "Curious George"},
  {name: "Harry Potter"}
]);
```

And this will have created 2 models in the lib collection with the corresponding names, right?

Comment: yes that would create 2 models in the lib collection;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw object in this case is just a simple object (Not a already constructed model)

In this example, the collection is of type `Book` (which is a model which might have some predefined attributes and default values)

```
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Book
});
```

So Library is a collection `Book` models.

If you want to create a new Book as part of the Library, you can go about in 2 ways.

**1.) Create a Model first and add it to the collection**

```
var book1 = new Book({
    id: 1,
    name: 'abc'
});

Library.add(book1);
```

**2.) Pass in the Raw attributes to the Collection directly.**

```
Library.add([{id: 1, name: 'abc'}]);
```

Comment: in the first method, why do you have to add book1 to the Library? Isn't all Book models part of the Library collection already since you first defined the model: Book as part of the Library collection?

Comment: The model can exist on it's own as an entity. But if you want that to added to the collection, then you have to explicitly add it to the collection. Only then will it be part of the Library.

Comment: oh, then what is the purpose of the first part? -
 Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Book
});
does this just mean that everything you #add will be a model of of type Book?